# How to measure phase angle of 3 phase by microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, three-phase

I am currently using PIC18F452, trying to measure the phase angle of 3 phase. How can I measure this. What feature of PIC can I use to solve it.

Comment: Is this 3 phase power from the utility that can be assumed to be at a constant and accurate frequency, or something else?

Comment: Measure it relative to what?

Answer (score 1):

With the information given in your question, we can't be too specific here. Basically, you can use the ADC and CCP module and/or Timers (or just the timers depending on if you want any other information as well), with some external circuitry to (possibly isolate) adjust and buffer the levels.

Comment: connecting one phase to an IO pin through a very large resistance (\$10M\Omega\$) is the simplest way to detect zero crossings.

Comment: Yep, that comes under "external circuitry" ;-) The OP seems to want to know which parts of the PIC can be used. Hard to say anything more without extra info from the OP.